# Pass variable to function even if not set

Tags: php

In my templates I use a function called `balance()`.

```
function balance($authUser = null) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The `balance()` function accepts an optional parameter: `$authUser`.

The `$authUser` variable is not always set, so depending on where `balance()` is used in the app an error is thrown from time to time.

Of course I can do the following to check if `$authUser` is available, and if not set it...

```
$authUser = isset($authUser) ? $authUser : null;

if($balance($authUser) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But this feels gross and is clunky and I'd have to do it in multiple spots and I'd rather not if there's another way.

Is there a way to just do something like this, so that if `$authUser` isn't set an error will not be thrown?

```
if(balance(isset($authUser))) {
    // do stuff
}
```

#### Update

Here's the `balance()` function

```
function balance($authUser = null)
{
    if(auth()->guest()) {
        return [];
    }

    // if $authUser is set, just return it
    if($authUser) {
        return $authUser->account->balance;
    }

    // otherwise lookup the balance in the database
    return auth()->user()->getBalance();
}
```

Comment: is $authUser a object?

Comment: What does the `balance()` function do

Comment: Defining vars before using them may feel *gross and is clunky* but thats what you should do. You could do `balance((isset($authUser) ? $authUser : null))` but that's worse imo.

Comment: You can pass argument by reference in your function definition, `function balance(&$authUser = ...`. Then `isset(..)` checks, can be ignored

Comment: @Akintunde Returns an integer. I've updated my question with the function.

Answer (score 2):

there.

I'm not quite sure if I have understood your doubt. But you could put a verification in your `balance()` method, like this:

```
function balance($authUser = null) { 
    if (!$authUser) return false;

    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  Sounds like this variable _should not be optional_, if it throws errors when it isn't provided.

Comment: This doesn't prevent an `undefined variable` error if `$authUser` isn't set prior to calling the `balance()` function.

Comment: It's probably better to check on `is_null()` since you are expecting it not to be null when $authUser is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an if condition before calling the `balance()` function

```
if(!empty($authUser)) {
//call balance function 
balance($authUser); 
}
```